# R - Carry forward 1 until another 1 reached

Tags: r, algorithm

I have a vector of zero and ones `v <- c(0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0)`. What I want is a function `func` do is to carry forward `1` until the next `1` is reached starting from the left, and then stop. If there is a new 1 after that, then the process should begin repeat. If a subsequent `1` is not found, `1` will be carried forward until the end of the vector. So here:

`v` is `c(0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0)`

`func(v)` should give `c(0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0)`

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Why are there no ones in `1, 0, 0, 1`?

Comment: Starting from the left, an unpaired 1 should be carried forward until its pair (the next 1) is reached only. Then the rest of the vector `c(0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0)` should be considered anew to find the next set of paired 1's.

Comment: does the algorithm fill holes of `0`s between paris of opening and closing `1` with ones? Considering that once a `1` is considered a closing `1` it can't be considered as an opening `1` for the potential following `1`.

Comment: @user1984 Zeros are not filled after the closing 1. The first 1 encountered beginning from the left is the first opening 1, the next 1 is the paired closing 1, and that's the end of that sequence. The next 1 is going to be a new opening 1.

Comment: right, that's what I understood from the example.

Comment: what if `z <- c(1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like a run-length encoding problem:

```r
func <- function(z) {
  r <- rle(z)
  ind <- which(r$values == 0)
  r$values[ ind[seq_along(ind) %% 2 == !(r$values[1] == 0)] ] <- 1
  inverse.rle(r)
}
func(vec)
#  [1] 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 0
```

Walk-through:

- First, a run-length encoding gives each unique value and the *consecutive* repeats for it, so

  ```r
  rle(v)
  # Run Length Encoding
  #   lengths: int [1:9] 1 1 3 1 2 1 1 1 1
  #   values : num [1:9] 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0
  ```

  Interpretation: the first value is a `0` and it has 1 instance; the second is a `1` (with 1); the third is a `0` with 3 instances; .etc.
- From there, knowing that we can call `inverse.rle(r)` to regenerate the original `v`, we need to replace alternating `0`s with `1`: to know *which* we need to replace depends on the first value: if the first is a `0`, then we need to replace the *even* instances of `0` within `r$values`.

  `seq_along(ind) %% 2` determines if a specific `ind` (indices of `0`) is an even or an odd index; `!(r$values[1] == 0)` gives us the correct odd/even component we want.
- Once we know which (evens or odds) need to shift from `0` to `1`, we just reassign it, and see

  ```r
  r
  # Run Length Encoding
  #   lengths: int [1:9] 1 1 3 1 2 1 1 1 1
  #   values : num [1:9] 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 0
  ```

  It may be clear from here that if we invert it back into a vector, we should get one `0`, one `1`, three `1`, one `1`, two `0`, etc, exactly what we want.

Comment: In func, what is ind? Getting an 'ind' not found error

Comment: typo/omission, thanks ... fixed

Answer (score 1):

I think an easy way is uing `pmax` + `cumsum` + `%%`.

Hope the following code can give you some hints:

```
> pmax(v, cumsum(v) %% 2)
 [1] 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 0
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
def fill_holes_with_ones(arr): 
    found, idx = False, -1 
     
    for i, el in enumerate(arr): 
        if found and el == 1: 
            for j in range(idx, i): 
                arr[j] = 1 
            found = False 
        elif el == 1: 
            idx = i 
            found = True 
    return arr
```

The above code is in python but since this is primarily an algorithmic question and python is easy enough to read I think you can translate it with relative ease.

This algorithm runs in `O(n)` time complexity (maximum 2 pass) and `O(1)` space.

The idea is to have a flag to indicate if you have already found an opening `1` or not. Also have an index that keeps track of the last found opening `1`. If you have already found an opening `1` and see another one, set all elements between the index that you previously captured and the current index to `1` and set the flag to False to invalidate the previous opening. Otherwise, if you find a `1` it only means that you have found an opening `1`, set the flag to true and capture the current index for potential later use.

Answer (score 0):

A solution based on converting the numeric vector to string and back to numeric vector:

```r
library(tidyverse)

v <- c(0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0)
z <- paste(v,collapse = "")

z %>% 
  str_extract_all("(10+1)") %>% 
  unlist() %>% 
  reduce(
    function(x,y) str_replace(
      x,
      paste0("(?<!1)",y), 
      paste(rep("1", nchar(y)), collapse = "")),
    .init = z) %>% 
  str_split("") %>% 
  unlist() %>% 
  as.numeric()
#>  [1] 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 0
```